# Очень долго загружается Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, оптимизация, fancybox

Здравствуйте. Хочу попросить совет у вас. Есть [многостраничный сайт](http://nashedom.ru/), на сайте куча js скриптов, все работает хорошо. Но на одной из страниц сайта (для зареганых пользователей, в личном кабинете, страница объявления -> добавление объявления) скрипт  ( просто модалка fancybox) работает очень медленно. На остальных страницах все работает быстро и без нареканий ( ссылка, которая вызывает скрипт располагается в шапке сайта). Медленно он загружается на странице где есть форма, которая так же выбирает города, регионы итд ( код ниже). Данные берутся из контекста! В Хроме загрузка идет 25-28 секунд. в FireFox - 2,5 сек.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
{% load hosts %}
<div class="b-header">
    <div class="b-header__menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="b-menu">
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                        <span class="b-menu__item btn_change-location">
                        <a href="#change-location" class="fancybox dashed">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            Просмотр объявлений на территории:
                            {% if user.districts.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for district in user.districts.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ district }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ district }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for district in user.districts.all %}
                                    <span>{{ district }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if user.regions.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for region in user.regions.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ region }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ region }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for region in user.regions.all %}
                                    <span>{{ region }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if user.cities.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for city in user.cities.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ city }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ city }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for city in user.cities.all %}
                                    <span>{{ city }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                                Просмотр объявлений на территории:
                        {% endif %}
                           
                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Шаблон модалки ( получение данных из контента)**

```html
{% load hosts %}
{% load widget_tweaks static %}
<div id="change-location">
<form action="{% host_url "setlocation" host "www" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div id="chose-city-wrap">
        <div class="b-modal__title">Выберите ваш город</div>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.country.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.country }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.districts.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.districts }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.regions.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.regions }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.cities.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.cities }}
            </div>
        </p>


        <br />

        <div class="b-modal__item b-modal__item_btn">
            <input class="b-btn b-btn_red" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**Форма загрузки городов на странице где тормозит модалка!**

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend>Территория распространения объявления</legend>

        {{ form.country|add_class:"b-input__input js-select" }}
        {{ form.districts|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {{ form.regions|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {{ form.cities|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {# form.geo|add_class:"b-input__input" #}

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Карма плохая, настроение у программиста паршивое было, духи машины гневаются. Ну серьезно, вопрос в духе "почему моя программа не работает?", без отладки не сказать.

Comment: @Утка Это я понимаю что все тут не телепаты, просто может сталкивался кто, в чем могут быть причины такого поведения, когда везде отлично работает, а на одной странице около 10 секунд грузит скрипт...

Comment: так долго, что происходит? грузит скрипт по сети? дом перерисовывает? или логика виснет? или память какой-то хренью забивается? или например со скриптом вдобавку грузится порно с конями? (не ну а чо бы не загрузить, вот эту иконку для кнопки "закрыть" надо же откуда-то взять). В консоли разработчика есть инструменты для отладки всего этого

Comment: По всего лишь коду шаблона невозможно воспроизвести проблему, дайте что-нибудь такое, что мы запустим и что у нас тоже станет тормозить

Comment: @b-ars07, очистите кэш браузера, откройте в браузере инструменты разработчика на вкладке "сеть" и загрузите страницу вашего сайта. Покажите эту временную схему загрузки.

Comment: @Visman [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/n2YVb57UD7WaA6)

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, скриншот с начала до 2-й секунды загрузки (там наиболее долгий процесс). Для этого выделите мышкой нужную область на временном графике. А еще было бы неплохо написать название скрипта с popup окном.

Comment: @Mikl загружается модалка через fancybox. вот в чем прикол в firefox работает отлично. в Хроме загружается именно на этой странице секунд 25-28

Answer (score 2):

Если скрипт стоит в шапке, то стоит посмотреть что грузится перед ним. Это, вероятно, css и другие скрипты. На этой странице в css могут быть указаны какие-нибудь большие картинки, например. Посмотрите вкладку network в консоле разработчика, чтобы точно узнать, что именно грузится.